# Problems when creating new notes in Simplenote using Simperium

Tags: c#, simperium

I'm creating an Open Source C# client for Simplenote using Simperium API. Almost everything is ready, but I am facing problems when creating a new note.

How I can create a new note in Simplenote using Simperium API?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the app id and API key you can create new notes just like creating any Simperium object as referenced in the [documentation](https://simperium.com/docs/reference/http/#objectpost).

The bucket to post to is `note` and it'll also need to conform to the schema in the following sample note:

```
{
    "tags" : [ "todo", "later" ],
    "systemTags" : [],
    "creationDate" : 1335390338.091436,
    "modificationDate" : 1335390338.091436,
    "deleted" : false,
    "shareURL" : "",
    "publishURL" : "",
    "content" : "new note content!"
}
```

All fields are needed when creating, but you can just specify the fields that have changed when updating.

Comment: Thanks for the bit about `note` being the bucket. I hadn't been able to find that out anywhere else.

Comment: One thing I'm not clear on: is there anyway to have Simperium/Simplenote generate the object id for you like you could under the old Simplenote API?

Comment: I guess you have to create your own now? Based on the Python library and how it uses `uuid.uuid4().hex`

Comment: Correct, you have to generate your own